# Changing touch event source on Mobile Safari

Tags: mobile-safari, touch-event

I have two overlapping images. I touch the topmost image and start moving (`touchmove`) finger around. All subsequent `touchmove` events are received by that image. In the middle of this interaction I want the events to go to the image underneath, so that I can move it around instead.

How to change the event source to the image underneath? That is, once an object has started receiving touch events, how do I change the target of those events?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Joe Blow is talking about handling touch events in the context of a native iPhone app built with Objective-C.

Eric's question is about handling touch events in Mobile Safari with JavaScript.

I could be confused though...